Compensation claim declined by easyJet
On 18/10/24 I was travelling from London Gatwick to Barcelona with easyJet. Our flight was due to depart at 17:45. At 13:30 we were emailed that the flight was delayed, no problem always expect some delay when travelling with easyJet. At 17:20 I received a message that our flight was cancelled, was offered a hotel but declined as I don’t live too far away and eventually took a taxi home. Was offered a flight the next afternoon which was an hour late, but all good. On return I completed an online compensation claim and received an email a fortnight later saying ATC staff shortages had put flight crew into exceeding their  legal hours and therefore out of their control. So my issue is at the time of cancellation 17:20 our flight was not even scheduled to take off so how is that possible that the crew were already out of hours and that it wasn’t easyJet’s fault. Is this an acceptable appeal?

It sounds as if the crew were waiting for a clearance to fly, but at some point their legal hours were exceeded and had to stand down. Thus the flight was canceled. That they were not scheduled to take off is not the point. The reason why, while they had not exceeded their time, they could not take off is of importance (the airlines fault or not).

Just try again with them. The first answer is often no, but if you insist they may change. It is just an unethical way to to a first screening. Else try with British aviation authority (they have own faqs).

@GiacomoCatenazzi Firstly, easyJet rejections come from a no-reply email address, so the system isn't designed for you to challenge their decision. Secondly, the British aviation authority doesn't handle easyJet complaints; they outsource it to AviationADR, which appears biased in airlines' favour unlike CEDR, which also doesn't deal with easyJet

So they are acting like staffing (something entirely within their company's control) is some kind of act of God outside of their control... and they think that excuse will fly? It's as amusing as it is infuriating. May as well say: "We planned poorly, so not our fault."

@Mentalist But, but, AtC rEsTrIcTiOnS!!!

If they're being a stick in the mud, threaten to go to the CAA. If they think they've got a weak case they'll probably pay up. They might stand their ground but worth a try.

@Crazymoomin CAA doesn't take on easyJet cases

@Crazydre CAA doesn't get a choice. If an airline is registered in the UK it has to accept and arbitrate complaints about it.

@Crazymoomin Well it won't do so, end of! Only if the airline isn't subscribed to any CAA-approved ADR scheme (AviationADR for easyJet). For airlines the CAA do handle, though, they only provide an opinion, NOT an enforceable decision, unlike the ADR schemes

Thanks all for your help.

@Crazydre The CAA can use an ADR if it wishes. Many airlines don't want to go through the effort of arbitration. If easyJet has a weak defence it may roll over then. It's at least worth trying first rather than wasting half the compensation on a paid solicitor (that means single tickets on short to medium haul are barely worth fighting).

@Crazymoomin My point is: CAA outsources easyJet claims to AviationADR, and they only 15% of cases there are ruled in favour of the claimant, vs. 86% at CEDR who handle British Airways, Cathay Pacific and SAS

@Crazydre Well there's no harm in threatening or enquiring. Then you can decide if it's worth the risk for full compensation. As I said, for short to medium haul it's barely worth the effort if your law firm takes half the money. For example, this related question did so successfully with easyJet.

Airlines will frequently lie about the real cause of disruptions - and lose when taken to court by someone who can argue the case well.
I'd recommend filling out the form at Flight Delay Compensation Claims, and it'll say based on internal records whether your flight is likely to be claimable. If it says it is, you may wish to enlist that firm or a similar one. The linked one frequently wins against easyJet in UK court and pays you 58% if they win for you.
A free-of-charge alternative is AviationADR, but they'll basically buy any airline defence that looks sophisticated enough without really analysing it critically. easyJet's paralegals write quite eloquent defences, so unless you can solidly disprove it, you stand little chance.

Wow, they keep 42%, and you still have to add VAT on top. Others keep "only" 35% VAT included. Don't know their respective track records, though.

@jcaron why would you add VAT? There's no supplied product/service.

@SamDean that looks a lot like the services of a law firm to me… the fact that they bill on the basis of the compensation received does not quite change the nature of the work…

@jcaron OT but where I am if I use a lawyer to get compensation, and 99% goes to the lawyers fees, I'm still on the hook for the full 100% as income for my taxes even though I only get 1% of the settlement!
